# customer portal

Tags: customer-portal

I'm using the customer portal to my customers. I have the Services object, when I click on view, the related lists are collapsed due to the large number of results that are shown.

I would like to enter on the view and show the related lists expanded. I did the override of the view this way

```
<apex:page standardController="Services__c" action="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}?nooverride=1&rowsperlist=50">
```

But on the customer portal it won't work. Anyone can help me? I have extreme urgency on fixing this for my customers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do your portal users have READ access to the Services object (check in the profile)?